# NSJSONSerialization to Core Data

Tags: ios, json, core-data

I'm having a programming getting some json data into core data. I can get the entity populated, the problem comes in when I'm trying to populate the relationship's entity.

I've tried many different things but this is what I have right now:

```
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization
                      JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                      options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                      error:&error];

Group *groupModel = [NSEntityDescription
                     insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Group"
                     inManagedObjectContext:context];

//NSLog(@"%@", jsonArray);

for (NSDictionary *array in jsonArray)
{
    groupModel.name = [array valueForKey:@"name"];

    NSSet *itemSet = [array valueForKey:@"items"];
    NSLog(@"%@", itemSet);
    groupModel.deck = itemSet;

    for (NSDictionary *item in [array valueForKey:@"items"])
    {
        //groupModel.deck = telephoneSet;
    }

    //NSLog(@"%@", [array valueForKey:@"name"]);

    //NSLog(@"%@", [array valueForKey:@"items"]);
}
```

I've tried all sorts of things to get this data inserted and I can't figure it out. I know that my class Group has a relationship with Deck:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *deck;
```

So I'm trying to pass an NSSet converted from json but I can't exactly figure it out. I've tried looping through it all sorts of different ways and converting it to different types.

```
[
    {
        "name": "Default",
        "items": [
            {
                "name": "Name 1",
                "weapon": "Weapon 1",
                "type": "Type 1"
            },
            {
                "name": "Name 2",
                "weapon": "Weapon 2",
                "type": "Type 2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The Items from the array need to be converted into a set and passed to the group property. That is the part I can't figure out.

Deck.h:

```
@interface Deck : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * info;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * type;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * weapon;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Group *group;
```

Group.h

```
@interface Group : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *deck;
@end

@interface Group (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addDeckObject:(Deck *)value;
- (void)removeDeckObject:(Deck *)value;
- (void)addDeck:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeDeck:(NSSet *)values;
```

Comment: Show the model / entity class headers. Consider looking at RestKit.

Comment: Also, why would you name a dictionary variable `array`, and `itemSet` will be an `NSArray`, even if you hope it might be an `NSSet`...

Comment: I added the class headers

Comment: Wain, like I said I've been working on this for a long time. I've changed the code a lot and tried a lot of different things. I didn't change the variable arrays every time I tried something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd encourage you to use RestKit to help with this.

You have one main fundamental issue:

1. You never create any instances of `Deck`. You need to. You're trying to set an array of dictionaries to `deck` which expects a set of `Deck` objects.

Basically, in your `for (NSDictionary *item ...` loop the first thing you should be doing is creating a `Deck` instance. Then configure it using the `item` dictionary contents. Then call:

```
[groupModel addDeckObject:deck];
```

(don't bother trying to set an `NSSet` with all the `Deck` objects are you need to iterate anyway).

Comment: I swear I tried to do that and it kept saying something about my one to many relationship and crashing. This time it did work though so thank you. I looked at RestKit a little bit but I'll check it out again.